# How to Edit Display of Products in Catalog View Page in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, catalog

Please visit this link :

http://www.whiteboard-shop.co.uk/whiteboard_school/fixed_wall_mount.html

Here , 1)On the products image box, We have an option to add "QUANTITY".

2) Also there is a text " Delivery in 1-2 working days".

I wanted both above options in magento site.

This is my list.phtml => http://pastebin.com/4BM3UySS

Please help in finding solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question already has been answered.

[how-to-add-quantity-option-to-each-product-item-in-the-category-list-page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/20975/9824)

For the "Delivery in 1-2 working days , you could create an custom attribute and insert it in the list.phtml, or just insert the sting in as plain text.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for reply. I am new to magento. How i can enter "text" in list.phtml can you please look at my list.phtml file above and edit the code and paste in pastebin or can you help me in which line , i have to add the text.